# How can I solve the mistake of killing the process?

Tags: c#

I am a high school student, then I am preparing for a cybersecurity competition recently. I wrote a program that constantly detects and kills the process, but I don't know what went wrong. It runs fine for a while and then exits. How can I fix it?

source code ↓

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace defense
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList white_list = Get_process();
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    ArrayList bad_list = Get_process();
                    foreach (int pid in bad_list)
                    {
                        if (!white_list.Contains(pid))
                        {
                            Process.GetProcessById(pid).Kill();
                            Console.WriteLine($"process {pid} dead.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        static ArrayList Get_process()
        {
            Process[] pss = Process.GetProcesses();
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            foreach (Process ps in pss)
            {
                list.Add(ps.Id);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it and open several programs:

```
process 10776 dead.
process 11580 dead.
process 12152 dead.
process 10660 dead.
请按任意键继续. . .
```

It runs normally for a while and kills a few processes and then quits.
What's going on here?

Anyway, thank those who gave me advice, I hope you have a good day.

Comment: You're running it in a tight loop. The OS might just kill your app out of pure exhaustion.

Comment: Why are you using an `ArrayList`? That's so 2002.

Comment: Also, never write code with a `catch (Exception)` (especially so with one that does nothing). You should only ever catch **specific exceptions** that you can **meaningful handle**.

Comment: well, i just recently started writing c# code... 

Comment: The other thing that you might want to consider is that you're really messing with the OS. Why are you killing any new process? What's up with that?

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity, How can I prevent the operating system killing my app?

Comment: The only reason I can see for killing all new processes is malware. The OS should kill your app, as should any halfway decent anti-malware or antivirus software.

Comment: I am writing a defense program that can kill any new process...

Comment: That's not a *defense program*. That's a malware program that kills new processes, which prevents users from running any application. It's also apparently [not your first question about malware](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55792479/62576).

Comment: I am going to participate in the offensive and defensive competition. This is the magic weapon I used to defend my server... I am not a bad guy  @KenWhite

Comment: If you're entering a competition, you should be solving the problem yourself. Asking us to do it is cheating, which means you're not *competing*. Not sure how *malware* + *cheating* equals *not a bad guy*. :-)

Comment: Can I ask, what's the point? Surely a GPO or something would be a better approach? Maybe it's just me but there are few things unclear about this whole process.

Comment: i am not cheating , I am preparing for the competition now, this is just testing my new defensive ideas.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I were writing an app to do what you're doing, I might consider writing it this way:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> good = Process.GetProcesses().Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
        List<int> bad = Process.GetProcesses().Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        foreach (int pid in bad.Except(good))
        {
            Process.GetProcessById(pid).Kill();
            Console.WriteLine($"process {pid} dead.");
        }
    }
}
```

Killing processes like this is a bad idea though.

Comment: @李雨泽 - Please don't learn this. It's a bad idea. You should solve your problem some other way. This is a disaster waiting to happen. It could literally and permanently corrupt your operating system.